# While Statement and Divs

Tags: php

I am trying to get the code below to loop using a while statement. The problem I am having is getting the divs to worth with in the PHP. Any ideas on how I can make this happen? My database consists of a columns called month, day, description, and location.

```
<div class="events-module">

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("sandbox", $con);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events"); ?>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) ?>

<div class="date">
<div id="month"><h4><?php echo $row['month']; ?></h4></div>
<div id="day"><h3><?php echo $row['day']; ?></h3></div>
</div>

<div class="event">
<div id="description"><p><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p></div>
<div id="location"><p><b><?php echo $row['location']; ?></b></p></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile;

 mysql_close($con);

 ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say exactly what's wrong.  But, it seems you are missing your start block for your while loop

```
while (.... )  :
              ^^^
... // div stuff
end while
```